# Pick 2 items with same contestId from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to pull 2 videos from this array of videos that share the same contest id. Doesn't matter what the contest ID is, as long as both of the items share the same value. This might be easy but I'm at one of those points where my brain is fried. I can smell the bbq. lol.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [filename] => 7966727971960279-4131736221448300-Adele_Set_Fire_to_the_Rain_Cover_by_Sara_Niemietz_
            [added] => 2013-05-06 08:50:34
            [userId] => 14
            [contestId] => 3
            [complete] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [filename] => 7090052934711575-3964279645504194-Adele_Set_Fire_To_The_Rain_cover_by_Sabrina
            [added] => 2013-05-06 09:58:08
            [userId] => 14
            [contestId] => 4
            [complete] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [filename] => 6959153088629946-5656902896285110-Adele_Set_Fire_to_the_Rain_Cover_By_Public_School_Kids_Own_With_Guitar
            [added] => 2013-05-06 09:42:10
            [userId] => 14
            [contestId] => 4
            [complete] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [filename] => 2795880037180269-1520875971490576-test
            [added] => 2013-05-06 08:02:53
            [userId] => 9
            [contestId] => 3
            [complete] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [filename] => 6683752765687164-9656171421456902-Adele_Set_Fire_To_The_Rain_Arlene_Zelina_Cover_
            [added] => 2013-05-06 09:21:12
            [userId] => 11
            [contestId] => 3
            [complete] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [filename] => 6917133659214044-8729839283435145-Adele_Set_Fire_To_The_Rain_Boyce_Avenue_cover_on_iTunes_Spotify
            [added] => 2013-05-06 09:34:50
            [userId] => 12
            [contestId] => 3
            [complete] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Tried doing it with mysql but can't figure out how to pull 2 records that have matching contestId's without knowing the contest ID before the start of the query. Have tried a session based solution looping through contest Id's that are currently active, but was way to bulky and buggy.

Comment: There may be more than 2 records which match that criteria - which would you want to be returned? The first 2, last 2, at random, something else?

Comment: Random. Just 2 random videos with matching contest Id's is what i'm after.

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of this? - [Narrow down array to 2 items with identical Id's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454916/narrow-down-array-to-2-items-with-identical-ids?rq=1)

Comment: That question has been deleted. This one is more clear in my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store them in an array with each element being an subarray with all elements sharing same `contestId`:

```
$sorted = array();

foreach ($elements as $e) {
    $sorted[$e['contestId']][] = $e;
}

print_r($sorted);
```

**EDIT**

This function will give you an array with two elements with the same `contestId`, or null if not found. If you don't need them to be random, remove the `shuffle()` call.

```
function getElementsFromArray($elements, $numberOfElements = 2) {
    shuffle($elements); // In case if you want different elements in each call
    $sorted = array();

    foreach ($elements as $e) {
        $contestId = $e['contestId'];
        $sorted[$contestId][] = $e;

        if (count($sorted[$contestId]) == $numberOfElements)
            return $sorted[$contestId];
    }

    return null;        
}
```

Comment: This definitely sorts the videos into arrays by contest ID, but I'm not seeing how its going to help me select 2 from one of the arrays that match. Seems like it wouldn't work correctly every time. Especially in the instance where the first array only had 1 result, but the second, third, fourth array etc, had plenty of results to pull 2 videos.

Comment: This works perfectly and I understand the solution best. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: This will return you the first two videos of the first contest id that it finds repeated. If you need more than two or if you need for all repeated ids, I think you can modify this template for your requirement.

```
<?

$vidArr = array();
foreach($arr as $ar)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($ar['contestId'],$vidArr)) 
    {
        $vidArr[$ar['contestId']] = $ar['filename'];    
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Found two videos '". $vidArr[$ar['contestId']] ."' and '".$ar['filename']."' for ContestID ".$ar['contestId'];
        exit;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yours works too btw, the other just fits my need a bit better. I sincerely appreciate your help on this. THANKS!